My cat has a balding spot on her chest
I'm feeling concerned about my cat. I just discovered a bald, bumpy spot on her chest with a yellow scab on top, and I suspect it might be from a fight with another cat a few days ago. I’m planning on taking her to the vet, but I’d appreciate any thoughts or suggestions. Thank you!

what is your question?
